# should I declare constructor in prototype in js?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
function User (theName, theEmail) {
    this.name = theName;
    this.email = theEmail;
}

User.prototype = {
    constructor: User,
    changeEmail:function (newEmail)  {
        this.email = newEmail;
        return "New Email Saved: " + this.email;
    }
}
// A User 
firstUser = new User("Richard", "Richard@examnple.com"); 
firstUser.changeEmail("RichardB@examnple.com");
</script>
```

This code it taken from here: http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/

Question:

Is that nessecerry to put this line: `constructor: User,`? If I removed this line, it still work.

Comment: It’ll still work, but `constructor` will be wrong and you might want to use it.

Comment: Please do not believe in the myth that Javascript is an object oriented programming language - as it is not.

Comment: @ed: funny, i though about everything in js was an object, no wonder it's so buggy...

Comment: @Ed Heal: what does your comment bring to the discussion? A holy-war provocation?

Comment: @dandavis: in js **not everything** is an object. A number literal `1` is not an object, but a primitive type value.

Comment: @op: you don't need to put constructor there, not sure what it would do for you in that code anyway...

Comment: @zerkms - The simple fact that Javascript is not OOP. I know that the prototype mechanism is flawed in trying to convince people that it is. Why use this mechanisms when it cannot access closures and anything belonging to this.

Comment: @Ed Heal: my question was - why did you comment like that? How does this help to OP with his issue and to us with helping OP to solve his issue? Would this "fact" change something in the solution? I understand you just want to argue about that with someone, but please just don't.

Comment: @ed: this can be used to create generics and pure functions that get an extra argument not formally passed. you can use a factory or an anon wrap if you want closure from constructor to prototype, but the model discourages that and rewards single/many capability separation...

Comment: @EdHeal: I think you're just confusing terms here. Object oriented programming is independent of the inheritance model. JavaScript is fully object oriented; `prototypes` is the answer for inheritance. What makes JS object oriented is `this`, that's it.

Comment: Javascript is NOT OOP. It does not have information hiding. Prototypes cannot access `this`. No such thing as private methods/data. You can fake all this - granted - use closures etc - if you go through loops and barriers. Just because a programming language implements associative arrays and enables one to link functions to a variable (what language does not) does it make it OO?

Comment: @EdHeal: what do you mean by "Prototypes cannot access this" ?

Comment: @EdHeal: I guess we just have different notions of what OO language is. Seems like the same issue occurs with the definition of "functional language". I would say JavaScript is both OO and functional. Classical inheritance and encapsulation are extras that complement OO patterns.

Comment: @elclanrs - Lets forget about programming for a moment. An object (say a car) has a set of attributes. It has a fuel tank (so does a lorry). A fuel tank has a certain operations (methods). How much (fuel gauge), put fuel in. Do I care that internally that it stores the contents in imperial or as a SSI unit. We could press a button on the dashboard and the fuel tank object will provide the answer. Now lets think of a fuel tank on a satellite - it cannot use a dipstick to measure the quantity of fuel. Yet needs the same result. Inheritance and abstraction comes into play.

Comment: @EdHeal: Could you provide a snippet of how you'd do that in OO according to your definition in any language of your choice? Just a quick set-up of the classes.

Comment: @elclanrs - `class FuelTank { public: virutal void AddFuel(int quantity, UNIT unit /*Gallons etc - an enum */) = 0; virtual int HowMuch(UNIT unit /* as b4 */);} = 0; class CarsFuelTank : public FuelTank ( /* implemented using a dipstick */}; class SatelliteFuelTank : public FuelTank { /* implemented using the fact that heating fuel to a certain temperature and letting it cool to another temperature takes a certain amount of time depending on the quantity of fuel */ }; `

Comment: @EdHeal: Here's how you could do this by just using only objects and the `this` context, which is what according to my definition makes JavaScript an OO language. Of course you wouldn't do this in the real world since `prototypes` exist, but I guess it explains my point. http://jsbin.com/ofasah/1/edit. The essence is the same, but without all the extras that complement this pattern. You could also use the new `Object.create` to do something similar in a "modern" way.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ofasah/2/edit. Just leaving the working example after a couple edits.

Comment: @elclanrs - Where is the prototype bit?

Comment: @EdHeal: Well that works without protoypes, that's the concept of OO I wanted to show. But with `prototypes` you don't need to `return this` or worry about the context. Here's how I do it with prototypes http://jsbin.com/ufeqot/2/edit

Comment: @EdHeal: Forgot the line that makes inheritance work http://jsbin.com/ufeqot/3/edit `CarFuelTank.prototype = Object.create(_super.prototype);` If you want to keep talking about it we should probably move this to the chat.

Comment: @EdHeal Please consider learning how JavaScript works, and how OOP works before making such statements. You're not only reducing the overall quality of the site, you're making a fool of yourself. I'd start with reading about strong behavioral subtyping, start with "Barbara Liskov, Jeannette Wing, A behavioral notion of subtyping, ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems (TOPLAS), Volume 16, Issue 6 ". Second, I'd consider "Taylor, David A. (1992). Object-Oriented Information Systems - Planning and Implementation.". Your perception of OOP looks strongly misguided and misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we create a new object in javascript using either `new` operator or `{}`, the newly created object's constructor property points to the constructor function. In your case:

```
firstUser = new User("Richard", "Richard@examnple.com");
```

`firstUser.constructor` is `User`.
 The same holds true for your `User.prototype`. When you use `{}` to create a new object for `User.prototype`, the constructor property is `Object`. When you put `constructor: User`, you just change the constructor property from `Object` to `User` and your code still works.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to do that if you replace the default prototype with a new object, as you're doing with `User.prototype = {...}`. You can just extend the default prototype instead:

```
User.prototype.changeEmail = function (newEmail)  {
   this.email = newEmail;
   return "New Email Saved: " + this.email;
}
```